# External CSS background Image

Tags: html, css

I do not understand WHAT I am doing wrong. I'm new to this and just trying to follow this online course...

So I have my HTML file and all I'm trying to do is shove my tiny bit of CSS into a separate `.css` file.

When I use `< link rel="stylesheet" href="./Documents/Untitled1.css >` in the head tag of my HTML file, referring to my CSS code that just states a basic CSS, the background does not change...

HOWEVER, if I use the style tag inside my head tag... it works JUST fine using my CSS code.

```
body {
   
 background-image: url("./images/rain.jpg");
    
background-repeat: no-repeat;
    
background-size: cover;
  }
```

Please someone tell me what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Hi, please make sure that the paths of the files are correct. Look that you need a " in the end of here <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Documents/Untitled1.css >, so it has to be < link rel="stylesheet" href="YOUR_PATH/FILENAME.css">

Comment: please check your CSS path, may be a path issue

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
body{
    background-image: url('https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-under-mist-morning-amazing-260nw-1725825019.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-size: cover;
 }   
</style>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stack.css">
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
```

I think your CSS href path I guess !! not sure you can check the above code

Answer (score 0):

Name your styles file "style.css", put style.css to the same folder where you have your *.html file and inside html file paste this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
```

Your issue is caused by wrong path to css

Answer (score 0):

you have a whitespace character between tag opening and the link keyword

```
< link rel="stylesheet"...
```

should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet"...
```

also - do you really have your css in Documents folder?

Answer (score 0):

I know what's wrong here, I have faced this issue so many times. The background image doesn't show up because you haven't set a height to it.

```
body {
 height: 100%
}
```

This will do the work.
[Reference](https://jsfiddle.net/z9xj61qp/)

Answer (score -1):

is your HTML and CSS in the same folder?
If yes then just use

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Untitled1.css">
```